# Making AutoMoq return Fixture-created values for methods

Tags: moq, autofixture, automoq

I'd like to explore wether we can save time by setting that all Moq-mocks created by AutoMoq should by default return Fixture-created values as method return values.

This would be beneficial when doing a test like the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Client_Search_SendsRestRequest()
    var client = fixture.Create<Client>();

    // Could be removed by implementing the mentioned functionality
    Mock.Of(JsonGenerator).Setup(j => j.Search(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(create("JsonBody")));

    client.Search(fixture.Create("query"));

    Mock.Of(client.RestClient).Verify(c => c.Execute(It.IsAny<RestRequest>()));
    Mock.Of(client.RestClient).Verify(c => c.Execute(It.Is<RestRequest>(r => record(r.Body) == record(client.JsonGenerator.Search(query)))));
}
```

Note that the generated values must be cached inside (?) the proxies, we want the same value "frozen" in order to check. Also, setting up the mock with `Setup` should override the created value.

So, how can we modify AutoMoq mocks to do this?

A simple test verifying that it works could be:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MockMethodsShouldReturnCreatedValues()
{
    Guid.Parse(new Fixture().Create<ITest>().Test());
}

public interface ITest
{
    string Test();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely possible, just use the `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization` instead of the `AutoMoqCustomization`. The mocks will use the fixture to generate returns values for all its methods, properties and indexers (*).

Properties will be evaluated eagerly, whereas indexers/methods' return values will be evaluated and cached when invoked for this first time.

(*) There are two exceptions to this rule - the customization cannot automatically setup generic methods or methods with `ref` parameters, as explained [here](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#more-information-16). You'll have to set those up manually, with the help of the `.ReturnsUsingFixture` method.